how to link node@16 with other version of it using homebrew?
I got this error and node is not working
I tried to install and link node@16 and I expect it to br linked and work on node16.0 version as I am developing web3 Dapps(decentralised apps). In the ubuntu it says "node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when I write the command node --version
